# Am I using the srand function properly?

Tags: c++

When I run the program it works, but once I submit my code against the test cases, they all fail.

Heres what I have.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int classA[10];
int classB[10];

int main()
{
    int seedValue;
    cin >> seedValue;
    srand(seedValue);

    int i;
    double sumA = 0;
    double sumB = 0;
    double avgA;
    double avgB;

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        classA[i] = rand() % 101;
        classB[i] = rand() % 101;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        sumA = sumA + classA[i];
        sumB = sumB + classB[i];
    }
    avgA = sumA / 10;
    avgB = sumB / 10;

    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Class A average is: " << avgA << endl << "Class B average is: " << avgB << endl;

    if (avgA < avgB)
    {
        cout << "Class B wins!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Class A wins!"<< endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

for input 1 my program returns

```
Class A average is: 46.50
Class B average is: 47.00
Class B wins!
sh: 1: Pause: not found
```

However, it should look like this...

```
Class A average is: 44.00
Class B average is: 41.20
Class A wins!
```

I feel like the same numbers aren't being generated which is causing the output to be different. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Same as what? Where does your expected output come from?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)` This accesses your arrays out of bounds. Use `< 10` instead.

Comment: @melpomene probably their CS instructor, by the looks of this question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that did it! thanks for the help

Comment: @Justin : Consider using `std::vector` instead.